# Integrate $\int{ \frac{z - Ru}{(R^2  + z^2 - 2Rzu)^{3/2}} du }$

Tags: integration

This integral comes from a physics book when calculating a field of an uniformly charged sphere (without Gauss' Law).

It says that it can be done by partial fractions, but I cannot imagine how.

Comment: well, the derivative of $R^2+z^2-2Rzu$ is twice the numerator.  Perhaps that gives you a hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As GEdgar pointed out in a comment, this is

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)^{3/2}}\mathrm du\;,$$

with $f(z)=R^2  + z^2 - 2Rzu$, so perhaps the easiest way to do this is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)^{3/2}}\mathrm du
&=&
-\int\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}f(z)^{-1/2}\mathrm du
\\
&=&
-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\int f(z)^{-1/2}\mathrm du
\\
&=&
-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\int(R^2  + z^2 - 2Rzu)^{-1/2}\mathrm du
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\frac{(R^2  + z^2 - 2Rzu)^{1/2}}{Rz}\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If it is indeed the integral with respect to $u$ that you want, and $z$ is an oddly named constant, make the substitution $w=R^2+z^2 -2Rzu$.  Despite appearances, this is a simple linear substitution.

Go through the process, not forgetting that $dw=-2Rz du$.

You end up with an integral of the shape
$$\int \frac{A+Bw}{w^{3/2}} dw.$$
where $A$ and $B$ are somewhat messy constants.
Split the integrand into two parts, $A/w^{3/2}$ and $B/w^{1/2}$.

If in your integral $du$ is a typo for $dz$, life is even simpler, make the same substitution, and you end up with $dw/2$ on top.

Comment: I'm sorry for the $z$, it was actually a constant (in the problem it was a parameter btw). So, this solves the problem!

Comment: @pygabriel: No problem! One cannot expect notational conventions in another field to be the same as those in a first-year calculus course.  It did fool me for a moment though, I saw $du$ and read $dz$.  It can be useful to give messy constants temporary new simple names.

Comment: @pygabriel: The solution by joriki  uses "differentiation under the integral sign," a powerful set of techniques that it is useful to know. It is the solution that ought to have been "accepted"!

Comment: thank you for pointing me that! At a closer look joriki's solution seems quite appropriate for the case, simplifying a lot the problem. Thank you again for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{R^2+z^2-2Rzu}=t$ and then differentiating both sides gives

$\dfrac{-2Rz}{2\sqrt{R^2+z^2-2Rzu}} du = dt$, which is equivalent to $\dfrac{-Rz}{t}du=dt$. Substituting this,

$\displaystyle \int{ \frac{z-\frac{R^2+z^2-t^2}{2z}}{t^3} \frac{-t}{Rz} dt}=\int{ \frac{-R^2+z^2+t^2}{2z} \frac{-1}{Rzt^2} dt} = \frac{1}{2Rz^2} \int{ (\frac{R^2-z^2}{t^2} -1) dt}$.

I guess you can do it now.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-1}^{1}{z - Ru \over \pars{R^{2}  + z^{2} - 2Rzu}^{3/2}}\,\dd u}
=\int_{u\ =\ -1}^{u\ =\ 1}\pars{z - Ru}\,
\dd\pars{1/\pars{Rz} \over \root{R^{2}  + z^{2} - 2Rzu}}
\\[5mm]&=\left.{1 \over Rz}\,
{z - Ru \over \root{R^{2}  + z^{2} - 2Rzu}}\,\right\vert_{\,u\ =\ -1}^{\,u\ =\ 1}
-\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over Rz}\,{-R \over \root{R^{2}  + z^{2} - 2Rzu}}\,\dd u
\\[1cm]&={1 \over Rz}\pars{{z - R \over \root{R^{2} + z^{2} - 2Rz}}
-{z + R \over \root{R^{2} + z^{2} + 2Rz}}}
\\[5mm]&\phantom{=}+{1 \over z\,d_{>}}
\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd u \over \root{1 - 2\pars{d_{<}/d_{>}}u + \pars{d_{<}/d_{>}}^{2}}}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
d_{<} & \equiv & \min\pars{\verts{R},\verts{z}}
\\[2mm]
d_{>} & \equiv & \max\pars{\verts{R},\verts{z}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> In the last integral, the integrand can be expanded in *Legendre Polynomias*
>   $\ds{\,{\rm P}_{\ell}:\bracks{-1,1} \to {\mathbb R}}$, with
>   $\ds{\ell = 0,1,2,3,\ldots}$, which satisfy
>   $\ds{\int_{-1}^{1}\,{\rm P}\ell\pars{x}\,{\rm P}\ell'\pars{x}
>      ={2\,\delta_{\ell\ell'} \over 2\ell + 1}}$. Then,

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-1}^{1}{z - Ru \over \pars{R^{2}  + z^{2} - 2Rzu}^{3/2}}\,\dd u}
\quad\pars{~\mbox{Note that}\ \,{\rm P}_{0}\pars{x} = 1\,,\
\forall\ x \in \bracks{-1,1}~}
\\[5mm]&={\sgn\pars{z - R} - \sgn\pars{z + R} \over Rz}
+{1 \over z\,d_{>}}
\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{d_{<} \over d_{>}}^{\ell}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{-1}^{1}\,{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{u}\,\dd u}
^{\ds{=\ \dsc{2\,\delta_{\ell,0}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large%
{1 \over z}\bracks{{\sgn\pars{z - R} - \sgn\pars{z + R} \over R} +{2 \over d_{>}}}}
\end{align}

> where
>   $\ds{\quad\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
> d_{<} & \equiv & \min\pars{\verts{R},\verts{z}}
> \\[2mm]
> d_{>} & \equiv & \max\pars{\verts{R},\verts{z}}
> \end{array}\right.}$